# Spread result of android Adaptor across multiple listview

Tags: android, android-listview

How can Show result of one adaptor across multiple listview ?
at the moment i can fill all of listviews with one adaptor :

```
private ListView List;
private ListView List2;
MyAdapter  adapter;
MyAdapter MA = (MyAdapter) List.getAdapter();
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Result = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Result = MA.getData();
    adapter = new Custume_LazyAdapter(targetCtx, Result);
                    List.setAdapter(adapter);
                    List2.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and MyAdapter Class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> BigData;
  public MyAdapter(Activity activityinput, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ArrayInput) {
        activity = activityinput;
        BigData=ArrayInput;
    }
        public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getData(){
        return Bigdata;
    }
```

and layout :

```
     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/ase"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/list"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:paddingRight="1dp"
         android:scrollbars="none" />

      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/list2"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:paddingRight="1dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

this is order of item in list and how it should be displayed in layout :

[image: Order OF listview in layout]

Comment: Why would you want two `ListViews` with the exact same data on one activity?

Comment: @hichris123 as shown in image im implementing something like StaggeredGridView with listview.same data will spread across both list view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can Show result of one adaptor across multiple listview ?

You don't. You create two adapters, each with the proper information for its `ListView`.

> and MyAdapter Class:

Split your `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` into two instances of `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`, each having the proper half of the values. Then, you create two instances of `MyAdapter`, one for each of your new `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` instances, and put one `MyAdapter` in each of the two `ListView` widgets.

Comment: Thanks that was it !
I made two adaptor and to arralist with hashmap.
thanks alot :)